# symfony FOSJsRoutingBundle generate url

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

Can someone help me understand how to generate url with FOSJsRoutingBundle?

I have a route :

```
            /**
 * @Route("/ajax/send/mail/assistance/{center}/{ind_stu}",
 *     defaults = { "center" = 1 ,"ind_stu"=1},
 *     options = { "expose" = true },
 *     name = "ajax_stu_sendmail_assistance",
 * )
 */
    public function sendmailassistanceStuAction(Request $request,$center,$ind_stu,\Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
```

in my jquery file i write

```
var path =Routing.generate('ajax_stu_sendmail_assistance',{ $center:center,$ind_stu:ind_stu});
```

i want that the url to call :

`/ajax/send/mail/assistance/nr_center/nr_ind_stuf`

but i don't know why it calls :

`/ajax/send/mail/assistance?%24center=nr_center&%24ind_stuf=nr_ind_stuf`

It works for another example when i use only 1 variable, can somone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mistake in generate route syntax. Please remove `$`

```
var path =Routing.generate('ajax_stu_sendmail_assistance',{ center:center,ind_stu:ind_stu});
```

Please check this https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

Try flipping the arguments (the first is the key) as follow:

```
var path =Routing.generate('ajax_stu_sendmail_assistance',{ center:$center,ind_stu:$ind_stu});
```

Hope this help